# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in an angular2 application

Tags: rest, angular, talend

I am trying to consume a rest webservice (invoked by Talend Open Studio for ESB job) in an angular2 application but when i run my application, i get this error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8088/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: That's a pure server side issue. If the server doesn't respond with the expected `Access-Control-Allow-xxx` headers, you're not supposed to use this API. You can use the `JsonpModule` to workaround if the requests don't need custom headers to be sent.

Comment: You should read about https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Your local server should have Access-Control-Allow-Origin set, so that another server is able to access it

Comment: the problem is resolved, the webservice which i've done with talend must have the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" in the Response header(shown in the network field in the browser console ) .So to avoid this error we should add the access-control-allow-origin attribute in the header of the tRESTResponse element in the talend open studio

Answer (score 0):

When I have this issue and i cant do nothing in server, i just use concurrently and corsproxy like dev dependencies in my package.

"concurrently"

"corsproxy"

and add this script to package:

"dev": "concurrently --kill-others 'corsproxy' 'ng serve -o'"

Now you need configure your angular project to make request to the proxy, in my case I add this line to my enviroments file:

apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:1337/serverUrlApi'

And in my Http interceptor add this line to all my request.